# How do I split an equation on operators but keep negative numbers?

Tags: java, arrays

This is what I currently have:

```
String[] arr = expression.split("[*=+\\-]");
```

It works perfectly fine for an equation like 123*456=56088 where the result is [123, 456, 56088] but doesn't work for something like this:
19 - -45 = 64.

How do I change the code to work for an equation like this so it would result in this array: [19, -45, 54].

Thank you.

Comment: Consider that two operators are allowed in some circumstances.

Comment: I'll have to see if I can find some time to develop a regular expression for this (usually we use another tool, BNF), but to what Mad Physicist is mentioning, we typically think of there being two operators with the same symbol.  There's a subtraction operator `a '-' b` where a and be are "terms".  The second operator is the negation operator `'-' a`.  If you think about how you want '-' to get parsed, you'll realize that there's only a small set of cases where '-' can be a negation.  Capture those in your expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Java doc for "negative look behind". You have to separate - and +

something like that

`split("[*=\\]|(?<![*-+=\\]\s*)[+-]")`

Comment: Thank you for the help. It seems like this: "[*=+]|(?<=[0-9])[\\-]" works for what I'm trying to do. I'll have to read through the lookbehind doc more.